# creating makefile that updates word count of textfile?

Tags: makefile, macros, word-count

I'm currently trying to write a simple makefile that updates the word count in a .wc file of a .txt file whenever it is changed. Here's the code for the makefile:

```js
foo.wc:foo.txt
 wc foo.txt > foo.wc

%.wc: %.txt
 wc $*.txt > $*.wc

clean:
 rm *.wc
```

Typing 'make clean' in the command line works fine after I've run 'make,' which creates a .wc file for the word count of foo.txt. But, what I'm trying to do is make it work in the general case. **In other words, I'm trying to make a rule such that the makefile creates a .wc file for any .txt file.**

But when I type 'make new.txt' (new.txt is a non-empty textfile in the same folder), I get "make: Nothing to be done for 'new.txt'" printed to the shell. Can anyone help me with what's going on here? Is this possibly a syntax error or something else?

Comment: Type `make new.wc` instead of `new.txt` ;-)

Comment: When you type `make thing`, the `thing` should be the thing that you want Make
to *make*, not something that you want it to be made *from*.

Comment: Also add a `-f` flag to your clean target (`rm -f *.wc`).  This will prevent it from failing and spitting out warnings if there are no files to remove.

Comment: awesome, thanks y'all! It works now that i've typed the command correctly. plus, I added the -f flag.